# Getting appropriate labels to show up in grouped DataFrameGroupBy.plot() legend

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering how to get the proper legend labels to show up in a DataFrame plot after grouped using the `group by` method. One would expect the legend labels to be the group names; instead they are showing up as redundant dependent variable names.

For example, I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     ECMO  Year Sex  Runs    p_ecmo
102   111  2011   M  2106  0.052707
104    31  2012   F  1801  0.017213
105    42  2012   M  2664  0.015766
107    59  2013   F  1039  0.056785
108    72  2013   M  1386  0.051948
```

And I am trying to group by `sex`, and plot `p_ecmo` by year. Thus,

```
ecmo_by_year[ecmo_by_year.Year>=1996].groupby('Sex').plot('Year', 'p_ecmo', grid=False)
ylabel('Proportion ECMO')
plt.legend()
```

But what I get is this, which is not helpful. The legend should display the group name, not the variable.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need `groupby` since you are not splitting, combining, or applying on p_ecmo

You can use a `pivot_table` to get the desired result.

`pt = ecmo_by_year.pivot_table(['p_ecmo'], rows='Year', cols='Sex').fillna(0)`
`pt['p_ecmo'].plot()`